# Mobx-state-tree actions not available in visual studio code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, mobx, mobx-state-tree

While model properties are listed in my visual studio code auto complete, the actions are not. Any idea how this could be improved?

[image: visual studio code autocomplete not working]

Comment: Maybe helpful, here is a documentation describing this issue: https://mobx-state-tree.js.org/tips/typescript

Comment: a [mre] would be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

One solution to this is this

```
const myModel = types.model({
  completed: types.boolean
})
  .actions(self => ({
    setCompleted(value: boolean) {
      self.completed = value
    }
  }))
  .actions(self => ({
    addStepResult() {
      // here you get autocomplete
      self.setCompleted(true)
    }
  }))
```

In the case you described not only that Visual Code is not autocompleting the actions but also Typescript fails to compile. In this case to bypass typescript, I hack it like this

```
(self as any).setCompleted(true)
```

I realize this is a hack but sometimes it's not worth to add the second `actions` call like in my sample code. A lot of times this hack backfired on me later down the line.